# Nodejs: not going in to the requestify

Tags: node.js

When I tried to get the response from the requested URL, I can get only printed statements of 'out' its not going in the requestify and how to get the response from requestify. Can any one tell me what is the error behind this.

```
console.log('out');
requestify.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(response) {
// Get the response body
console.log('in');
response.getBody();
console.log(response.body);
});
console.log('out');
```

Comment: I have added var requestify = require('requestify');

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Am not getting any error message, but buffering for long time. response: (out 
out
POST / 200 120003ms)

Comment: long buffering is not happen now but, I am getting same response.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add

```
var requestify = require('requestify');
```

above your code?

Also, due to the async behavior of NodeJS it will probably first display 'out'  twice and after you recieved a response from Google it will display the google homepage HTML.

Comment: Their is no response even after 30 min left as its. Their is no error returns and also no response.

Comment: Can you try the following code using a different module? If also this module doesnt work...I think it's your connection.
`var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})`